# Allowing my program to communicate without opening a routers port

Tags: java, sockets, connection, ports

Im trying to make a test chat program written in java to be able to send and receive messages. It works but to receive them you have to open the ports on your router. How can i get around this?

Comment: Use a port which is already open, or cast a spell on the admin so he looks the other way while you scribble down every packet on a paper slip and ship it off by carrier pigeon.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot without implementing a third party server which routes the chat between the two clients. This server would have the required incoming ports open, and would just forward everything.